Is there a way to move an entire Sub Json from cosmos to SQL Nvarchar (Max) via ADF
I am reading the value from cosmos and moving to SQL and since it is complex and unstructured we need to move that part of JSON from cosmos as nvarchar (max) in SQL.
I connected to Cosmos and cast a derived column as a string.

However, while adding in SINK as SQL, I am getting the error

Referencing is only allowed on structure types or array of structure types

How can I move Object type(Complex Json) as Nvarchar(max) for SQL?
